# Как сделать логику синхронизации субтитров по текущему времени?

Tags: java, android

Что могу

1. В реальном времени получить текущее время видео
2. Есть субтитры в формате srt

вида

1
00:00:06,240 --> 00:00:09,270
Если кто еще не в теме -
я Человек-паук

2
00:00:09,270 --> 00:00:11,740
И я очень спешу.

Как синхронизировать
если например сейчас получаю через метод в реальном времени youtube.getTime 9.1 секунда как вставить текст из второй строки?
Долго думал не могу логику придумать.

Comment: у вас есть время начала показа и время конца показа. В чем проблема найти те субтитры, у которых время начала меньше, чем текущее время видео, а время конца больше? И да, в 9.1 вы вроде должны первую строку показывать, а не вторую.

Comment: да, это не посмотрел 1 строку. Точно меньше текущего и если их несколько показать максимальный из них. спасибо конкретно простая задача оказывается.